# C# Textbox textchange property event

Tags: c#, user-interface, events, textbox

What is the best possible way to enable the visibility of a label inside a form.

If you see the code below .

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblgrpTwoFirst.Visible = false;
        lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = false;
        lblgrpTwoThird.Visible = false;
        lblgrpTwoFourt.Visible = false;
    }

    private void txtboxOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtboxOne.Text == "z")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Goose Eat the Beans");
        }

        else if (txtboxTwo.Text == "x")
        {
            lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = true;
        }
```

**Why does that label doesn't show up? But if try to make a messagebox . a messagebox pops up.**

Comment: Maybe because you have used `else if (txtboxTwo.Text == "x")` instead of `else if (txtboxOne.Text == "x")` ?!

Comment: If txtboxOne.Text == "z" then it would not matter whats inside the text of txtboxTwo if that's what you mean ... in this case remove the else from the else if

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks Tim for informing me.. i haven't seen it. my variable declaration is sometimes confusing.. btw thanks!

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger how about this : after typing a letter inside the textbox1. how can I focus , or the cursor will automatically transfer it to textbox2 ? What funciton should I use?

Comment: winforms been a while textbox2.Focus() ?

Comment: yeah its .Focus()... I am mostly using WPF nowadays

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger is WPF more convinient or widely used in industry? what is your advice for me?

Comment: WPF is more flexible and using a markup language to define the ui... all in all more flexibility, less pain, good learning curve too... if its just some textboxes and a table with some comboboxes winforms is good too though but if you want to style the ui (animations, special templates for buttons etc) you are screwed...

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the value of `txtboxTwo` in the `TextChanged` event of `txtboxOne`.

That is why `messagebox` block works and the later block does not.

Change it to:

```
private void txtboxOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtboxOne.Text == "x")
    {
        lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you indeed want to check txtboxTwo.Text dont use else if, use if:

```
 private void txtboxOne_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtboxOne.Text == "z")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Goose Eat the Beans");
        }

        if (txtboxTwo.Text == "x")
        {
            lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your conditions

```
 lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = txtboxTwo.Text == "x" ? true : false;
```

Comment: Wow, wow, wait a moment. Don't use the `?:` operator in this case.

Comment: @dymanoid Why? Are talking about a confilt with the previous condition While the CLR executing MSIL code ?

Comment: Simply because that's unnecessary here. `lblgrpTwoSecond.Visible = txtboxTwo.Text == "x"` is enough.